# Wrapping all inner methods with the same try-catch in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Consider this simple class:

```
class Foo {
    fun a(x: Int) = ...
    fun b(x: Int) = ...
    fun c(x: Int, y: Int) = ...
}
```

Any of the class functions might throw an exception. In that case I would like to log the input parameters of the method. I could either manually write the try-catch blocks in every single method - but they would make the code ugly and duplicate. Or - I could try to find some nice solution to keep the code tidy.

Is there a way to generate the try-catch block automatically and define what it should do? Something like:

```
class Foo {
    @WithTryCatch fun a(x: Int) = ...
    @WithTryCatch fun b(x: Int) = ...
    @WithTryCatch fun c(x: Int, y: Int) = ...

    fun executeOnCatch() {
        log.fatal(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would delegate that kind of stuff to an AOP system, and avoid polluting the code with those try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 5):

You could create an higher order function which you pass your code block to and handle the exception there:

```
inline fun <T,R> safeExecute(block: (T)->R): R {
      try{
         return block()
       } catch (e: Exception){
         // do your handle actions
       }
}
```

Now you can use it in your functions:

```
fun a(x: Int) = safeExecute{
   //todo
}
```

It’s an easy, clean and readable solution using simple concepts.

EDIT:

For enabling the error logging, you can pass a second argument of type `()->String` which will provide a message in case of an error.

```
inline fun <T,R> safeExecute(errorMsgSupplier: () -> String, block: (T) -> R): R {
      try{
         return block()
       } catch (e: Exception){
         // do your handle actions
         log.fatal(errorMsgSupplier())
       }
}
```

Comment: You also probably want: 1. additional `() -> String` argument to create the error message; 2. make the function `inline`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you’re right, I’ve added the inline, but using a function literal for a string? I don’t like to pass two lambdas if possible. Don’t you think a simple string is appropriate? `safeExecute(“error”){...}`

Comment: That doesn't allow logging the arguments of the method.

Comment: Yes it does- I’d pass the error message to `safeExecute` like suggested in the comments

Comment: If you just pass a string, it has to be constructed even if the exception isn't thrown and the message isn't needed. If the string is `"error"`, the cost is completely trivial; if it's `"c(${x}, ${y})"`, it may not be.

Comment: I think this helps, but it is not as elegant solution as proposed by @JBNizet.

Comment: elegant is not always the most readable, and for your situation I don't see the "benefit" outweigh the effort of implementng the AOP backed solution