# How can I handle catch exception for different functions at a common class in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exception

This is my RemoteDataSource class, where I'll write many api calls like this:

```
suspend fun getReviewData1() = getResult {
        try {
           apiService.getReviewData(getCustomerId())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
           handleException(e)
        }
    }

suspend fun getReviewData2() = getResult {
        try {
           apiService.getReviewData(getCustomerId())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
           handleException(e)
        }
    }
```

Now, you can see that for each fun, I need to wrap my code in try/catch block. Everything is working fine, I'm able to catch the exception also, but why to write so many try/catch for each function? Instead I need to do in one common class, so that I can simply call my function SOMETHING like this.

```
suspend fun getReviewData() = getResult {
     apiService.getReviewData(getCustomerId())
 }
```

You can write an answer and suggest me if you want to make change anything, for ex in getResult()

---

getResult() in another base class:

```
protected suspend fun <T> getResult(call: suspend () -> Response<T>?): Resource<T> {
        try {
            val response = call()
            if (response?.isSuccessful == true) {
                val body = response.body()
                if (body != null) return Resource.success(body, response.message(), response.code())
            }
            return error((response?.message() ?: context.getString(R.string.unable_to_reach_server)),
                (response?.code() ?: AppConstants.INetworkValues.DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return error(e.message ?: e.toString(), (call()?.code() ?: AppConstants.INetworkValues.DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE))
        }
    }

    private fun <T> error(message: String, code: Int): Resource<T> {
        LogUtils.d(message)
        return Resource.error(null, message, code)
    }
```

handleException()

```
fun handleException(e: Exception): Response<Any> {
        if (e is NoConnectivityException) {
            return Response.error(AppConstants.INetworkValues.INTERNET_ERROR_CODE, getDummyResponseBody())
        } else {
            return Response.error(AppConstants.INetworkValues.DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE, getDummyResponseBody())
        }
    }
```

I tried this answer, but it's just not happening:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517243/14016240

Please help.

Comment: most likely, you can add catch blocks for each type of exception you want handled, or within the catch(Exception e) block, you can use conditional statements to fire out which type it is, and to treat it accordingly

Comment: @Stultuske Ooops, I think you didn't understand my question properly. I'm not asking that inside catch block how can I handle the exception, I'm asking that for every fun, I'm wrapping my code inside try/catch block, that I don't want, instead it should be handle from any base class, and if exception is coming then it should go to catch block of that base class and return the logic from there only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getResult` function has an error in the catch block. You are calling `call()` again if the first call to `call()` threw an exception. I don't think it makes sense to call it again, because it will probably throw again and you won't be able to return your `Resource.error`.

If you fix this problem, you won't need to use try/catch in your other functions, because `call` will be safely wrapped in `try/catch` and pack any errors into a `Resource.error`.

To fix it: since you already handle `response?.code` in the try block, there's no reason to repeat getting `call()?.code` in the catch block. You can simplify it to

```
return error(e.message ?: e.toString(), AppConstants.INetworkValues.DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE)
```

Comment: Hey, exception is happening, because while api call is going through retrofit, I'm checking Internet connection inside interceptor class, and if no connection then I'm throwing NoConnectivityException that I'm catching write now inside handleException()

Comment: so it's not related to getResult() thing, exception is coming from retrofit side.

Comment: How can the retrofit exception escape your try/catch in `getResult()`?

Comment: Because the last point where I'm calling api is RemoteDataSource class, that's why exception is coming there, and getResult catch block can handle that particular try code, not this thing!

Comment: Also I tried one more thing for you. I removed try/catch and hit the api, but it's not going and catching in getResult, obviously it shouldn't go. Did you get my point?

Comment: Also getResult is not starting the API call, this line is starting it: apiService.getReviewData(getCustomerId())

Comment: Did you fix the line I said you need to fix? Your example functions in RemoteDataSource don't do anything besides creating a lambda function and calling `getResult()`. Since creating a lambda cannot throw an exception, the only way you will have an uncaught exception is if `getResult` throws an exception. If you fix the line like I said, `getResult` cannot throw an exception either. `apiService.getReviewData()` is called inside `getResult()` when it calls `call()`. It is not called directly in your RemoteDataSource function.